# spring cloud : Eureka handlers

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

Hi I am trying to call a custom method when a new instance/service is registered to eureka using Spring cloud api. Is there any handlers/interceptors are availble to perform this?  On completing the registration it should call the custom method, here i am trying to publish an event to the queue.

Answer (score 1):

There is an `InstanceRegisteredEvent` that is published as a Spring `ApplicationEvent`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have checked with EurekaInstnaceRegisteredEvent. But it does not return any event. can you explain somewhat detailed. Because I didn't understand in depth.